# парсинг olx.ua с помощью Python,beautifulsoup,requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Пытаясь сделать парсер мобильных телефонов на сайте olx.ua столкнулся с проблемой:при отправке get запроса мне выдает вместо корректного номера телефона "000 000 000",хотелось бы узнать у знающих людей в чем собственно говоря проблема и как её пофиксить.Желательно в рамках языка программирования Python(без JS и PHP)
Вот код:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.olx.ua/obyavlenie/vaz-2109-IDEcaGq.html"
ajaxUrl = "https://www.olx.ua/ajax/misc/contact/phone/"+ "EcaGq/"
r = requests.get(url)
c = str(r.content)
soup = BeautifulSoup(c,"lxml")


a = 1 
for i in soup.findAll("script"):    #цикл для поиска phoneToken'a в html файле
    a+=1
    if a == 24:
        token = i.text[36:164]
        break  



r2 = requests.get(ajaxUrl + token)    
print(r2.content)
```

Comment: Вижу ошибку в составлении гиперссылки, она должна быть вида `https://www.olx.ua/ajax/misc/contact/phone/{id}/?pt={token}`, т.е., допустим, `f'{ajaxUrl}?pt={token}'` в коде. Только это, наверное, мало что даст, сайт пишет куки в скриптах (один из скрытых чеков на роботов), а `requests` скрипты не выполняет и куки не пишет. Варианта два - либо извратиться, реверсинжинирнуть JS-скрипты, найти недостающий код с куками и переписать его в питоне, либо использовать что-нибудь типа `selenium`, где сайт открывается в браузере.

Comment: @hoefling, `requests скрипты не выполняет и куки не пишет.`, а https://github.com/psf/requests-html это сможет? :)

Comment: @gil9red интересный проект, не знал о таком. Спасибо за ссылку! Вроде да, `requests-html` рендерит страницу в хромиуме, [судя по коду](https://github.com/psf/requests-html/blob/dc82965d66761eed3b92ff371b8af9c4b85cc725/requests_html.py#L601).

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup не умеет парсить динамические страницы.

Для решения задачи парсинга динамических страниц лучше другой фреймворк, например, `Selenium`.

О нем можно почитать здесь: http://python-3.ru/page/selenium-python-example (рус)

или здесь: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html (eng).

Comment: пробовал через селениум,но выходит медленно.Кроме селениума нет никаких решений?

Comment: Selenium можно распаралелить...